# multiple routes with same url

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I currently have the following in my RouteConfig.cs:

```
            routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Identity",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Profile", action = "Identity" }
        );
```

I'm trying to use the following in a Action method:

```
return RedirectToRoute("Identity", new { @id = id });
```

but it doesn't seem to go there, when I check with Fiddler, i see the request is going back to the same page i was currently on, it appears to be hitting the Default route.  Is there anyway to force it to get the Identity one, even if their urls are the same, I want to use that to force users to the other controller when needed.

Comment: put the Identity one before the Default one?

Comment: As @zgood said, my understanding is that the default route config should be always at the end of the Route config. Since the route config will parse for matching configuration it will accept and route to that path. So if you specify the default configuration at the beginning it will always match and route to that path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MVC will stop looking for a route as soon as a match is found. In your case, it will look in the following order: 1.) Default 2.) Identity.

If you want to create a specific route with the same pattern, you can achieve it with the following code:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Identity",
    url: "Profile/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Profile", action = "Identity" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to 'Force' the user to another controller. It is a good practice to use the RedirectToAction method so you can supply the controller and action you want to bring the user to.

The solution supplied by @thiag0 will not work.

Use the following

```
return RedirectToAction("Identity", "Profile", new { id = 5 });
```

and in your Profile controller, make sure you can accept the parameter

```
    public ActionResult Identity(int id)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

and in RouteConfig.cs

```
            routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Identity",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Profile", action = "Identity"}
            );
```